# add list in to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i want this out put :
   RAM  Processor   LED     HDD     Price   waranty

```
   2GB core2due           12inch   300GB    30000    1year
   4GB    i3           14inch   500GB    40000    2year
   8GB dualcore           15inch     1TB    40000    1year
   2GB dualcore           12inch   500GB    40000    1year
  16GB    i5           15inch     1TB    30000    1year
   8GB core2due           12inch   300GB    30000    2year
```

but i don't get above out put 
my example is

that not provide this out put
code is of my example

```
parts=['RAM','Processor','LED','HDD','Price','waranty']
processor=['core2due','i3','i2','dualcore','i5','i7']
ram=['2GB','4GB','8GB','16GB','1TB','2TB']
price=['30000','40000','50000','60000','35000','29000']
hdd=['150GB','200GB','300GB','500GB','1TB','2TB']
waranty=['6month','1year','2year','3year','4year','5year']
led=['9inch','10inch','12inch','14inch','15inch','16inch']
com1={}
com2={}
com3={}
com4={}
com5={}
com6={}
j=0
shopcomputer={}
for i in range(0,len(parts)):
    com1[parts[i]]=ram[j]
    com2[parts[i]]=processor[j]
    com3[parts[i]]=led[j]
    com4[parts[i]]=hdd[j]
    com5[parts[i]]=price[j]
    com6=[parts[i]]=waranty[j]
    j=j+1
shopcomputer[1] = com1
shopcomputer[2] = com2
shopcomputer[3] = com3
shopcomputer[4] = com4
shopcomputer[5] = com5
shopcomputer[6] = com6
for i in parts:
     print '\t',i,
 print '\n',
 for no1 in shopcomputer:
    print shopcomputer[no1]['RAM'].rjust(10,),shopcomputer[no1]    ['Processor'].rjust(5,),shopcomputer[no1]['LED'].rjust(16,),shopcomputer[no1] ['HDD'].rjust(7,),shopcomputer[no1]['Price'].rjust(8,),shopcomputer[no1] ['waranty'].rjust(8,)

print shopcomputer
```

Comment: why make lists manually and then make a dicts?

Comment: So is your question about how to format the output or how to add lists to a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `format`:

```
>>> for x in range(len(parts)):
...     print("{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}".format(ram[x],processor[x],led[x],hdd[x],price[x],waranty[x]))
... 
2GB       core2due  9inch     150GB     30000     6month    
4GB       i3        10inch    200GB     40000     1year     
8GB       i2        12inch    300GB     50000     2year     
16GB      dualcore  14inch    500GB     60000     3year     
1TB       i5        15inch    1TB       35000     4year     
2TB       i7        16inch    2TB       29000     5year
```

Comment: it does not match the expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
parts=['RAM','Processor','LED','HDD','Price','waranty']
processor=['core2due','i3','i2','dualcore','i5','i7']
ram=['2GB','4GB','8GB','16GB','1TB','2TB']
price=['30000','40000','50000','60000','35000','29000']
hdd=['150GB','200GB','300GB','500GB','1TB','2TB']
waranty=['6month','1year','2year','3year','4year','5year']
led=['9inch','10inch','12inch','14inch','15inch','16inch']
info = [ram,processor,led,hdd,price,waranty]
com1={}
com2={}
com3={}
com4={}
com5={}
com6={}
j=0
shopcomputer={}
for i in range(0,len(parts)):
    com1[parts[i]]=info[i][0]
    com2[parts[i]]=info[i][1]
    com3[parts[i]]=info[i][2]
    com4[parts[i]]=info[i][3]
    com5[parts[i]]=info[i][4]
    com6[parts[i]]=info[i][5]
shopcomputer[1] = com1
shopcomputer[2] = com2
shopcomputer[3] = com3
shopcomputer[4] = com4
shopcomputer[5] = com5
shopcomputer[6] = com6
"""for i in parts:
     print '\t',i
     print '\n'
     for no1 in shopcomputer:
         print shopcomputer[no1]['RAM'].rjust(10,),shopcomputer[no1]    ['Processor'].rjust(5,),shopcomputer[no1]['LED'].rjust(16,),shopcomputer[no1] ['HDD'].rjust(7,),shopcomputer[no1]['Price'].rjust(8,),shopcomputer[no1] ['waranty'].rjust(8,)
"""
for i in shopcomputer:
    print i,shopcomputer[i]

output:

1 {'LED': '9inch', 'waranty': '6month', 'Price': '30000', 'RAM': '2GB', 'HDD': '150GB', 'Processor': 'core2due'}
2 {'LED': '10inch', 'waranty': '1year', 'Price': '40000', 'RAM': '4GB', 'HDD': '200GB', 'Processor': 'i3'}
3 {'LED': '12inch', 'waranty': '2year', 'Price': '50000', 'RAM': '8GB', 'HDD': '300GB', 'Processor': 'i2'}
4 {'LED': '14inch', 'waranty': '3year', 'Price': '60000', 'RAM': '16GB', 'HDD': '500GB', 'Processor': 'dualcore'}
5 {'LED': '15inch', 'waranty': '4year', 'Price': '35000', 'RAM': '1TB', 'HDD': '1TB', 'Processor': 'i5'}
6 {'LED': '16inch', 'waranty': '5year', 'Price': '29000', 'RAM': '2TB', 'HDD': '2TB', 'Processor': 'i7'}
```

I have corrected your dictionary formation , Now you can apply any formatting technique and print out the desired results .

Answer (score 0):

You need first to fix how you build the dictionary. Fortunately this can be done very easily by `zip`ping the lists together. Then using `format(**dict)` is the easiest way to format the output.

```
parts=['RAM','Processor','LED','HDD','Price','waranty']
processor=['core2due','i3','i2','dualcore','i5','i7']
ram=['2GB','4GB','8GB','16GB','1TB','2TB']
price=['30000','40000','50000','60000','35000','29000']
hdd=['150GB','200GB','300GB','500GB','1TB','2TB']
waranty=['6month','1year','2year','3year','4year','5year']
led=['9inch','10inch','12inch','14inch','15inch','16inch']

shop_computers = [dict(zip(parts, components)) for components in zip(ram, processor, led, hdd, price, waranty)]

for computer in [dict(zip(parts, parts))] + shop_computers:
    print "{RAM:>10}{Processor:^16}{LED:>7}{HDD:>8}{Price:>9}{waranty:>9}".format(**computer)
```

Answer (score 0):

With part of your code:

```
parts=['RAM','Processor','LED','HDD','Price','waranty']
processor=['core2due','i3','i2','dualcore','i5','i7']
ram=['2GB','4GB','8GB','16GB','1TB','2TB']
price=['30000','40000','50000','60000','35000','29000']
hdd=['150GB','200GB','300GB','500GB','1TB','2TB']
waranty=['6month','1year','2year','3year','4year','5year']
led=['9inch','10inch','12inch','14inch','15inch','16inch']
```

Then use zip

```
for row in zip(ram, processor, led, hdd, price, waranty):
    print '  '.join(['{:<10}'.format(x) for x in row])
```

The result:

```
>>> 
2GB         core2due    9inch       150GB       30000       6month    
4GB         i3          10inch      200GB       40000       1year     
8GB         i2          12inch      300GB       50000       2year     
16GB        dualcore    14inch      500GB       60000       3year     
1TB         i5          15inch      1TB         35000       4year     
2TB         i7          16inch      2TB         29000       5year
```